# Descargar image de recaptchap

Tags: python-3.x

Hola por favor necesito tuda con este problema, y es el siguiente:

Ando buscando como descargar la imagen de ReCaptchap, y no puedo ya e intentado esto:

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo')
input("..")
# get the image source
#

with open('captcha.png', 'wb') as file:
    
    file.write(driver.find_element_by_id('.rc-imageselect-instructions').screenshot_as_png)
file.close()    


driver.close()
```

Ya use xpath,fullxpath,id  y nada que puedo

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código le dará exactamente la misma imagen abierta en el navegador:

1. Presiona la URL:

```
driver.get(link)
```

2. Pegue el captcha completo xpath aquí:

```
ele_captcha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/span/div[1]/div/span[3]/img")
```

3. obten el captcha como una cadena base64

```
    img_captcha_base64 = driver.execute_async_script("""
        var ele = arguments[0], callback = arguments[1];
        ele.addEventListener('load', function fn(){
          ele.removeEventListener('load', fn, false);
          var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
          cnv.width = this.width; cnv.height = this.height;
          cnv.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
          callback(cnv.toDataURL('image/jpeg').substring(22));
        }, false);
        ele.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
        """, ele_captcha)
```

4. Guarda el captcha en un archivo:

```
    with open(r"captcha.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(img_captcha_base64))
```

para el alto y el ancho ->. cnv.width = ele.width; cnv.height = ele.height; Verifique el tamaño de la imagen captcha original descargándola en local. En ocasiones, el tamaño de la imagen original y el tamaño de la etiqueta de la imagen son diferentes en aquellos casos en que obtiene una imagen recortada o incompleta

Como se muestra abajo:

```
import base64
img_base64 = driver.execute_script("""
    var ele = arguments[0];
    var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
    cnv.width = 215; cnv.height = 80;
    cnv.getContext('2d').drawImage(ele, 0, 0);
    return cnv.toDataURL('image/jpeg').substring(22);    
    """, driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/span/div[1]/div/span[3]/img"))   #"/html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/span[3]/div[1]/img"))
with open(r"image.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(img_base64))
```

Comment: Hola Grasias, por responder, pero no me sirvio me dice lo siguiente: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Una
ble to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/div[2]/div[
3]/span/div[1]/div/span[3]/img"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)

el link es ('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo')

Comment: Me Puede servir tambien, Conseguir el link del SRC:

<div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 92px; height: 92px">
<img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq24QLWG8wnX62O36htxQDJGcezoTSvkjkhJnZuzHR-uouRK0FpGoHZ4NOJfl03RbaOaZs1aeqSC7t-Nq4ddlEpIIFzXPT1gXdEL86edwAZwgSzkEoBLNcc6UHbThxsbVkQYxBeswZsEN-tCkYRv8VAQpFJ4Kgg1WKUTjSKlwIuw7ol09q5MLvERt3Fcfbj460F81Ef__&amp;k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-" style="top:0%; left: 0%">
<div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div>

Comment: Compara el código del ejemplo con el tuyo e inténtalo de esa manera es la manera ideal, saludos.